# Background image repeat issue

Tags: css

I have 3 divs inside my div#all (simple html). Left - Main - Right.

Left & Right have just a background image (their content won't change).

Main div will have all my text etc.

**Option 1:** I need to have the left/right divs to expand their height (so my image background gets repeated) to reach the height that my divMain may have.

**Option 2:** I can do position:fixed my Left/Right divs as well so they stay in place when I scroll. My issue on this plan is that I cannot position/float my right div at the desired place.

Any working option is ok with me.

css code:

```
 body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
 overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;
}

#all{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 50%;
 height: 100%; width: 1366px;
 margin-left: -683px;
}

#temp-left{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 height: 100%; width: 183px;
 background: url(image/bg-lft.jpg) repeat;
}

#temp-right{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; right: 0;
 height: 100%; width: 183px;
 background: url(image/bg-rgt.jpg) repeat;
}

#main{
position: absolute;
top: 0px; left: 50%;
height: 100%; width: 960px;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: -500px;
text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: And your question is? You are very unclear at what you want :) And also add your html and make a fiddle that will represent your issue

Comment: @BojanPetkovski, repeat background only when there is a text overflow...

Comment: Your background will repeat in x and y axis if the width and height is bigger than the image. So by default it will repeat except if you specify it not to repeat :)

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your question i suggest you to use jquery
You can try this out.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Check if body height or width is higher than window height and width:)
    if (($("body").height() > $(window).height())||($("body").width() > $(window).width())) {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(image/bg-lft.jpg) repeat;');
    }
    else
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(image/bg-lft.jpg) no-repeat;');
});
```

Comment: dont forget to add jquery link